# Keynote - Random Elements and Shuffle Slides

Tags: keynote

In Keynote 6, if I have a slide with 2 images, how can I randomize the position of the images every time the presentation is run?

For example: Sometimes image 1 is at the top of the slide and image 2 is at the bottom. Sometimes it is opposite; image 2 is at the top of the slide and image 1 is at the bottom. Is this possible?

Comment: Is that even possible with any other presentation software?  e.g.: PowerPoint or Google Slides?

Answer (score -1):

In keynote there is an option called Magic move transition. So you can set image with magic transition , in each running the image position will get changed. For more [reference](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH16959?locale=en_US)

Comment: That is a cool feature, but I need to randomize the position of the images. Do you know how to make the position random?

Comment: In keynote you can't randomise the position i think so.